# PySpark : importing jars on runtime?

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to connect pyspark to mongodb.
The cluster is already set up, so I need a dynamic import of mongo drivers.

I have followed the docs (here and here [spark.jars](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)) and tried :

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
            .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri" , "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.coll")\
            .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.coll")\
            .config("spark.jars.packages"     , "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.1")\
            .getOrCreate()
```

But this :

```
df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("uri","mongodb://127.0.0.1/people.contacts").load()
```

gives me an error :

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o326.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/ConnectionString
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.MongoCompanionConfig$$anonfun$4.apply(MongoCompanionConfig.scala:278)
    at com.mongodb.spark.config.MongoCompanionConfig$$anonfun$4.apply(MongoCompanionConfig.scala:278)
```

From all the tutorials on the net it is unclear if we can upload packages during runtime, even if [spark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management)  seems to say it is possible.

The examples heavily relie on psark-submit". But I am myself using jupyter notebook, without spark included => I load it through the "findspark" function, and then declare my context.

Comment: It looks like spark found your package (there is information on MongoCompanionConfig in the log). Are you sure you loaded mongo connector version mathing your spark version (2.2x)?

Comment: You could try using `sc.addFile(filePath)` and see if it works.